# Spring Retry doesn't work with a try-catch block

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, spring-retry

I have a method that I want to retry when SQLRecoverableException occurs. I annotated the method with `@Retryable(value={SQLRecoverableException.class})` and enabled Retry in my application. However, this specific method includes a try-catch block to handle RuntimeException. The Retry is now not working because any exception gets caught in the try-catch block. I want the method to be retried for 3 times before the error handling. Is this possible with Spring Retry out of the box, or would I have to go for a more custom solution?

Comment: As far as I can see, [`SQLRecoverableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html) is not a `RuntimeException` and should thus not be caught by the `catch`-block (if the `catch`-block only catches `RuntimeException`s). Please [edit] the post and add the relevant code.

Comment: Please post the code. If you catch the exception in the method itself then of course Spring cannot act on it. If you catch it in another method that calls the method in question it should work.

Answer (score 1):

With Retry can be handled not only via annotation, so maybe this can help:

```
try {
    withRetry().execute(context -> {
        myMethodThatCatchException();
        return null;
    });
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    // ..
}

private RetryTemplate withRetry() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, Collections.singletonMap(SQLRecoverableException.class, true));
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Retryable(value={SQLRecoverableException.class},maxAttempts=3)
public boolean methodA(){
try{.....}
catch(RuntimeException ex){ // apart from given above one
\\handle catch exception
} 
}

@Recover
public boolean recoverMethodA(SQLRecoverableException a){
 logger.info(a.getMessage());
return false;
}
```

After some Observations i found -

- Retryable will not work with handled exception that you passing in retryable value.
- Retryable will not work if you are calling retryable method within another method in same class.
  ex  - boolean methodA() --> boolean retryableMethodB()
  in case you should to apply retryable on methodA.(if using controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch and rethrow specific exceptions inside try-catch block

```
@Retryable(value={SQLRecoverableException.class})
void someMethod() {
   try {
      ...
   } catch (SQLRecoverableException retryable) { 
       // don't handle here, let it be handled by @Retryable-mechanism
       throw retryable;
   } catch (RuntimeException other) {
       // handle other non-retryable exceptions
   }
}
```